# How to build Dimension Tables around Fact Table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am working on a CUBE built from a SQL Server 2008 environment.

I have a `FACT` table with these columns:

1. UserId
2. ServerName
3. DateTime
4. BytesReceived
5. BytesSend
6. Region

And few other columns. `Fact` table is build from join query written in a view.

I am having trouble on building dimensions.

If I have dimensions for Month, ServerName, Region, Year, Time - Cube Process failed.

For dimensions, every view will have `UserId` as the key column.

For example :

`DimServerName`:

1. UserId
2. ServerName

What could be the reason?

How to have Multidimensions for my `Fact` table.

Comment: Why would DimServerName have a UserId column?

Comment: I thought FactTable should be in StarSchema Relation. UserId column will build the relation for DImension Tables to the Fact Table. So i kept the UserId column to all the Dimension Table.